# Error when trying to run gazebo on macOS Catalina

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I try to run `gazebo9` on macOS Catalina 10.15.2.

I followed the [installation instructions](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_on_mac), specifically:

```
brew tap osrf/simulation
brew install gazebo9
gazebo
```

When I try to launch gazebo I get the following error:

```
gazebo --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 9.13.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 9.13.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.0.21
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.0.21
[Msg] Could not load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in "/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/plugins/" even though it was found.
[Err] [GuiIface.cc:123] This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen, webgl.
```

I tried to follow suggestions from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297627/qt-could-not-find-the-platform-plugin-cocoa) by setting `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/plugins/` which is where qt 5 exists after installing it with homebrew. xquartz is also installed using homebrew and works when I enter `xeyes`.

I can also confirm that `libqcocoa.dylib` exists in `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/plugins/platforms`. And trying with `gazebo11` results in the same error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24832/error-when-trying-to-run-gazebo-on-macos-catalina/) by [fjp](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25628/fjp/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For me the solution is to export the path to

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/plugins/platforms.
```

This makes sense somehow, as `libqcocoa.dylib` exists in `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/plugins/platforms` and not in `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/plugins/`.

---

Originally posted by [fjp](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25628/fjp/) with karma: 1 on 2020-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0